# How can I store sessoin data in session DB using authlogic plugin in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to store objects in session DB but authlogic plugin by default store  session in cookie. It does not let access session DB table. I could not figure out how to change session store in authlogic plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session store is not managed by Authlogic. You can use any session store you like. 
To change it to DB store, you have to add:

```
ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store
```

to your `config/environment.rb` file. Then, you must run:

```
rake db:sessions:create
```

More info:

- [ActionController API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html)
- [Post on tracking sessions](http://www.oopcenter.com/article/ruby-on-rails/tracking-sessions-in-ruby-on-rails-in-all-situations.html)

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your response. Actually I have tried whatever you said 2-3 times before I asking the help but it did not really work to
my app. session data is not stored in session table while I am using authlogic plugin [in my case].